# Is it possible to retrieve the MessageId of emails sent from Salesforce?

Tags: email

Is there any way to retrieve the MessageId of emails sent from Salesforce.

This is so that I can match replies received to such emails using the inReplyTo field of the Messaging.InBoundEmail record in an inbound email service handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to **Setup > Administration Setup > Monitoring > Email Log Files**. Then request for email logs for the duration you want. Salesforce will generate a CSV file with all emails. You can find MessageId in one of the columns.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that.
I was looking for a way to programmatically access this value.

Also, there doesn't seem to be any way to tie the Email Log entry back to the Activity History record.

Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Joe If it helps you, can you please mark it as answer.